# Calling python script from bash stops at command prompt

Tags: python, bash

I am calling a python script:

```
/bin/sh
python ~/Documents/Projects/Programming/Python/svg/svg2dxf.py $1 0
```

After running the script, I get a python command prompt ($) and it's only when I type "exit" at the command prompt that the script runs.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `$` is not the python command prompt, `>>> ` is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the following line:

```bash
/bin/sh
```

with ([shebang interpreter directive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix))):

```bash
#!/bin/sh
```

Otherwise, the new `shell` instance is invoked; until the new shell is exit, next line is not executed.

Comment: Oh, God, how did I must that? Thank you!

Comment: Both answers were acceptable. WHile attempting to click the accept button, I seem to have clicked the downvote button: sorry! Perhaps it would make sense to put the accept button above the up/down vote buttons?

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the leading:

```
/bin/sh
```

Your current script does two things:
1) execute a new instance of /bin/sh
==> which gives your the shell $ sign

2) execute the python script

Your script should be:

```
python ~/Documents/Projects/Programming/Python/svg/svg2dxf.py $1 0
```